# setting setting apps value in django for a new application

Tags: python, django

So I've been following [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/) and things worked well, but then I decided to try and write my own apps following the tutorial. I created a view, and updated the /`pysent/settings.py` file with this section

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pressent.apps.PressentConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

However, when I save the file, I get an error from the running server:

```
ImportError: No module named PressentConfig
```

If I change the first line above to only

```
`pressent`
```

I get no error message. On the other hand, with the tutorial example, things work with the line

```
polls.apps.PollsConfig
```

`django` version is supposed to be 1.9.6

```
>>> import django 
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 9, 6, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

What is going on here?

*Edit*
The solution was to edit `pysent/pressent/apps` and add

```
class PressentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pressent'
```

The reason to the problem was I changed the folder name.

Comment: So what is `apps` in your `pressent` directory? Is it a module? Does it contain a PressentConfig class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to presume `pressent` is your django application name (project name I think is `pysent`), so there's a directory named `pressent` and inside it has a `apps.py` file, and finally that file has a class named `PressentConfig`.

PressentConfig class example:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PressentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pressent'

    # Exec some configs for this app. Maybe overriding the ready method
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into your app directory, and check if there's a module named `app` and in that module a class named `PressentConfig`. If there isn't, then the app config approach will not work unless you create a configuration for your app. Read more [Django: configuring apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)